# How to draw a colored rectangle on a plot when x-axis is time?

Tags: matlab, datetime, plot, matlab-figure, rectangles

I want to draw a background rectangle behind some data. `Rectangle` does not support times as the x-coordinate or the width. Is there some other way of doing this?

Simple case:

```
time_data = datetime(2017,7,23) + duration(6,0:10:(60*14),0);
data = sort(rand(size(time_data)));
time_rectangle = datetime(2017,7,23) + duration([9 5+12],0,0);

figure(1)
plot(time_data,data)
hold on
plot([time_rectangle(1) time_rectangle(1)],ylim(),'--k','linewidth',1)
plot([time_rectangle(2) time_rectangle(2)],ylim(),'--k','linewidth',1)

ylimits = ylim();
rectangle(time_rectangle(1),ylimits(1),diff(time_rectangle),diff(ylimits))
```

(if rectangle worked the rectangle would be in front of the data but that would be easy to fix)

Answer (score 2):

You can use different axes for that. Instead of your last line above, type this:

```
xlimits = xlim(); % get the time limits
num_rectangle = datenum(time_rectangle); % convert the rectangle unites to numeric
axes; % add another axes
% add the rectangle only with numeric units:
rectangle('Position',... % draw a semi-transparent green rectangle
          [num_rectangle(1) ylimits(1) diff(num_rectangle) diff(ylimits)],...
          'FaceColor',[0.5 1 0.5 0.5],'EdgeColor','none')
xlim(datenum(xlimits)) % set the new axes limits to be the same as the the original axes
axis off % turn off the new axes, to see the only the rectangle
```

[image: rectangle]

Answer (score 1):

In R2020b and possibly earlier versions, the "fill" command can be used to draw arbitrary shapes, including rectangles, where the x axis consists of dates.
[This post](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/386598-using-datetime-data-for-x-axis-i-have-an-area-plot-on-the-whole-x-axis-and-i-create-a-fill-area-for) contains the info you need.